# Electron and Native Messaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am loading an extension that uses NativeMessaging inside an Electron app. When I launch the app, I am getting a "Access to the native messaging host was disabled by the system administrator." error. I have tried adding registry keys for Chrome Policies with no success.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Open `chrome://policy` and find the exact name and location of the applied policy.

Comment: I doubt Electron supports native messaging host. It doesn't even fully support Chrome extensions